# Calculating a percentage based on Group

Tags: mariadb, query

In order to get a percentage, you divide X by the Total and multiply by 100..

I am trying to translate this into a query and group by type to get a percentage of each type.

I have tried different variations of the same query

```
SELECT Type, (SUM(Inc + Exp) / (TotalInc + TotalExp)) * 100 AS Percentage
    (
     SELECT
        SUM(t2.Exp) 
     FROM  Table
     WHERE Date>='2022-04-01' AND Date<='2023-03-30'
    ) AS TotalExp,
    (
     SELECT
         SUM(t2.Inc) 
     FROM  Table
     WHERE Date>='2022-04-01' AND Date<='2023-03-30'
    ) AS TotalInc
        FROM  
            ( 
             SELECT 
                 COALESCE(Expense, 0 ) AS 'Exp',
                 COALESCE(Income, 0 ) AS 'Inc',
                 Type
             FROM  Table
             WHERE Date>='2022-04-01' AND Date<='2023-03-30'
             ) AS t2 
    Group By Type
```

Also tried

```
SELECT Type, (SUM(Inc + Exp) / (TotalInc + TotalExp)) * 100 AS Percentage
    (
     SELECT
        SUM(Expense) 
     FROM  Table
     WHERE Date>='2022-04-01' AND Date<='2023-03-30'
    ) AS TotalExp,
    (
     SELECT
         SUM(Income) 
     FROM  Table
     WHERE Date>='2022-04-01' AND Date<='2023-03-30'
    ) AS TotalInc
        FROM  
            ( 
             SELECT 
                 COALESCE(Expense, 0 ) AS 'Exp',
                 COALESCE(Income, 0 ) AS 'Inc',
                 Type
             FROM  Table
             WHERE Date>='2022-04-01' AND Date<='2023-03-30'
             ) AS t2 
    Group By Type
```

As well as countless other variations but no joy.

any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I think I was making this more complicated than it needed to be.

I managed to figure out the correct query, which is far simpler than the one above.

```
SELECT 
    Date, Type, (SUM(IncExp) / (SELECT SUM(IncExp) FROM Finance) * 100) AS Percentage
FROM 
    Table
WHERE
    Date BETWEEN '2022-04-01' AND '2023-03-31' )
GROUP BY 
    Type
```

IncExp is a new column (Expression) I created `Expense + Income`

Comment: Is `Finance` the `Table` in your example? Also, shouldn't the subquery use the Date filter, as the query in your question seems to suggest? Oh, and the closing bracket in the `WHERE` is a typo, I'm guessing.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with the help of window aggregation:

```
SELECT
  Type
, SUM(COALESCE(Expense, 0) + COALESCE(Income, 0)) * 100 /
  SUM(SUM(COALESCE(Expense, 0) + COALESCE(Income, 0))) OVER () AS Percentage
FROM
  Table AS t
WHERE
  Date BETWEEN '2022-04-01' AND '2023-03-31'
GROUP BY
  Type
;
```

The `SUM(...) OVER ()` syntax is the window version of the `SUM` aggregate function.  In this case, it aggregates the argument (which itself is an aggregate function) over the entire set (as specified by the empty brackets following the `OVER` keyword).

You can read more about window functions in the manual:

- [Window Functions - MariaDB Knowledge Base](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/window-functions/)